# AudioKit 4.5.0 Recorder example left channel only

Tags: ios, audiokit

In the Recorder example project for AudioKit 4.5.0, I am testing with standard earphone microphone on iPhone device. The playback is only in left channel. How to I record monophonic audio so it plays back through both channels?

Comment: I'll look into it, but thanks for being on top of the latest AudioKit version for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Send the stereo input into AKStereoFieldLimiter which can be set to turn the signal into a stereo signal of identical left and right channels.